# How to install MySQL WorkBench in Debian wheezy Operating System?

Tags: debian, mysql-workbench, mysql, debian-7.6.0

I tried to install MySQL workbench in Debian Operating System by using workbench for linux distribution, but its not working.

Comment: What is your error message? What is not working? What have you tried? Please provide more information

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

This will install mysql workbench ONLY on debian.
Both wheezy and Jessie.
Also works on ubuntu.

Comment: I get 'E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.' when I do this

Answer (score 2):

A common method is to use the operating system's package system. For Debian, MySQL recommends installing the [official APT repository](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and then use *apt-get* as you would normally. The official repositories contain most MySQL products and typically they are newer versions than the versions provided by vendors such as Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu, and so on.

So, for Debian, download the appropriate APT file and then execute something like the following (The mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb file name that you download might be different, so adjust that accordingly):

`cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community`

You might notice that both mysql-workbench and mysql-workbench-community packages will be available via apt-get, but *mysql-workbench-community* is the package you want. Use "*apt-cache show {insert package name here}*" on both packages to see the difference.

Installing the package file (mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb above) is a one time deal, so feel free to skip this step when updating Workbench or installing other MySQL products.

Comment: Currently workbench is not available for Debian Platforms in official APT repository. `MySQL Workbench (not available for Debian platforms)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-available